# Counting syllables in a list of strings Python without using RE

Tags: python, counting

I have to count the number of syllables in a text file. My problem is that I don't know how to iterate each character of each string. My idea was to check if a letter is a vowel, and if the following letter is not a vowel, increase the count by 1. But I can't increase "letter". I've also tried to use the "range" method, but I have problem also with that. What can I try? Thank you.
PS: I can only use Python built-in methods.

txt = ['countingwords', 'house', 'plant', 'alpha', 'syllables']

This is my code so far.

```
def syllables(text_file):

    count = 0
    vowels = ['a','e','i','o','u','y']

    with open(text_file, 'r') as f:
   
    txt = f.readlines()
    txt = [line.replace(' ','') for line in txt]
    txt = [line.replace(',','') for line in txt]
    txt = [y.lower() for y in txt]

        for word in txt:
            for letter in word:
                if letter is in vowel and [letter + 1] is not in vowel:
                    count += 1
```

Comment: This can be good reference https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46759492/syllable-count-in-python

Comment: There are some issues with your example: after `with open(...) as f:` there must be an indentation. If you remove all spaces you will not be able to separate words.

Comment: @cknoll I've seen it now, but in the IDE it is written in the right way. I remove whitespaces because in the real example there could be a whitespace in a string, between each character. But it was too long to post it here.

Comment: Withespace within words seems like a problem of the data source. This makes it ambiguous to count syllables. Wrt. the indentation: you should edit your post such that it displays correctly. This helps people in understanding your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might try this:

```
lines = ["You should count me too"]
count = 0
vowels = "aeiouy"

for line in lines:
    for word in line.lower().split(" "):
        for i in range(len(word)):
            if word[i] in vowels and (i == 0 or word[i-1] not in vowels):
                count +=1
print(count) # -> 5
```