# How to get complex words from a text file in python?

Tags: python, string, text, textblob

I have a text file. I want to get the sum of all the complex words from this text file.

Complex words here means a word which has more than 2 syllables, excluding some exceptions like words ending with "es","ed" by not counting them as a syllable.

Thanks

Comment: what is the format of the text file? how are the words separated?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: You can try using the NLTK package. https://www.nltk.org/api/nltk.tokenize.sonority_sequencing.html

Comment: maybe this will help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46759492/syllable-count-in-python